# Problem installing a package from KX Studio repositories

Tags: package-management, repository, music, ubuntu-studio

When I try to update a specific package I see an error:

Package failed to install Error while installing package: trying to overwrite usr/bin/DragonflyEarlyReflections', which is also in package dragonfly-reverb-standalone 3.2.1-0ubuntu1

I'm using Ubuntu Studio. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: We don't know your release, so can't look up for specific details currently.

Comment: What release are you talking about?